# Trying to add previous element in list to next element, but keep getting zero

Tags: python, list

I have a formula that uses the previous element to find the current element:

```
p(i) = 1 / (- 2 + p(i-1))
```

The code I have to find this is:

```
p = []
po = 0
i = .01

while i < 1:
    po = (-1) / (-2 + po)
    p.append(po)
    i = i + .01

print p
```

What I'm getting is :

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

My first value (if `po` is originally zero) should be `1/2`.

Any ideas why I'm only getting zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user @blhsing pointed out in his answer, the problem seems to be interger division: when dividing integers, the result is rounded down to yield a new integer.

By converting one of the arguments of the division into a `float`, the division will also return a `float`. It does not matter which of the 3 numbers you change into a `float`, changing one of them is sufficient to produce the correct result:

- change the initialization from `po = 0` to `po = 0.0`
- or change the divisiion to `po = (-1.0) / (-2 + po)`
- or change the divisiion to `po = (-1) / (-2.0 + po)`

---

Furthermore, I find your use of the `i` variable a bit strange. May I suggest a forloop using [`xrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange)?

```
p = []
po = 0

# the '_' is used to say "I dont care about this value", so this
# runs the loop the specified amout of times
for _ in xrange(10):
    po = (-1.0) / (-2 + po)
    p.append(po)

print p
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still new to Python, so I've never used xrange(). I will look into this now though.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2, a division involving only integers would always result in an integer, rounded down. You should use a floating number for division instead:

```
po = -1.0 / (-2 + po)
```